# Show Dialog depending on ViewPager state

Tags: android, dialog, android-viewpager

I have  a `ViewPager`, and lets imagine, that i am on page 0.

I have a button on this page, and on this button click, i want to show a dialog, and change page to the page 1.

When my page changes to page 1, i want the dialog to dissapear.

When i did it, i didn't see the dialog, it was appearing and dissapearing when page was changed, but i am sure, that i have 1000ms delay between this actions.

Please help, how can i show the dialog?

```
package com.example.ViewPagerDialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private int currentPage;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final MyViewPager viewPager = (MyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        final Button leftSwitcher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_switcher);
        final Button rightSwitcher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_switcher);
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        leftSwitcher.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Wait...");

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

            }

            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                currentPage = i;

                if (i == 0) {
                    leftSwitcher.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    leftSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rightSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    rightSwitcher.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });

        leftSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressDialog.show();
                sleepThread();
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage - 1);
            }
        });

        rightSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressDialog.show();
                sleepThread();
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage + 1);
            }
        });
    }

    private void sleepThread() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        View[] views = new View[3];

        public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            TextView view1 = new TextView(context);
            TextView view2 = new TextView(context);
            TextView view3 = new TextView(context);

            view1.setText("View 1");
            view2.setText("View 2");
            view3.setText("View 3");

            views[0] = view1;
            views[1] = view2;
            views[2] = view3;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return views.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return (view.equals(o));
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
            collection.addView(views[position]);
            return views[position];
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(android.view.ViewGroup container, int position, java.lang.Object object) {
            container.removeView(views[position]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the code you currently use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, never block the UI thread with `Thread.sleep()` like you do. By using `Thread.sleep()` you'll basically set the show command for the dialog(which will happen **after** you return from the `onCLick()` method), sleep one second(and your app will freeze) and then set the page on the `ViewPager` which will trigger the listener, dismissing the dialog. Instead you could use a `Handler` to

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

// in the onClick method
progressDialog.show();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage - 1);
    }

}, 1000);
```